# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pims' has no attribute 'pyav_reader' most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am trying to run my script but I am getting the following error, and i don't know what is the circular import which is the cause of this error, can anyone fix this pls

### AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 1>()

```
---> 1 from inference import convert_video
      3 convert_video(
      4     model,                           # The model, can be on any device (cpu or cuda).
      5     input_source=r"C:\Users\alaba\Desktop\RobustVideoMatting-master\test.mp4",
```

## A video file or an image sequence directory.

(...)
12     seq_chunk=12,                    # Process n frames at once for better parallelism.
13 )

File ~\Desktop\RobustVideoMatting-master\inference.py:22, in 
19 from typing import Optional, Tuple
20 from tqdm.auto import tqdm
---> 22 from inference_utils import VideoReader, VideoWriter, ImageSequenceReader, ImageSequenceWriter
24 def convert_video(model,
25                   input_source: str,
26                   input_resize: Optional[Tuple[int, int]] = None,
(...)
36                   device: Optional[str] = None,
37                   dtype: Optional[torch.dtype] = None):
39     """
40     Args:
41         input_source:A video file, or an image sequence directory. Images must be sorted in accending order, support png and jpg.
(...)
55         dtype: Only need to manually provide if model is a TorchScript freezed model.
56     """

File ~\Desktop\RobustVideoMatting-master\inference_utils.py:3, in

```
    1 import av
      2 import os
----> 3 import pims
      4 import numpy as np
      5 from torch.utils.data import Dataset
```

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pims_*init*_.py:1, in 
----> 1 from pims.api import *
3 from ._version import get_versions
4 **version** = get_versions()['version']

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pims\api.py:33, in

```
     31 try:
     32     import pims.pyav_reader
---> 33     if pims.pyav_reader.available():
     34         PyAVReaderTimed = pims.pyav_reader.PyAVReaderTimed
     35         PyAVReaderIndexed = pims.pyav_reader.PyAVReaderIndexed
```

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pims' has no attribute 'pyav_reader' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: Well I have solved this problem by installing another version of pims (v0.5), but it gave another error :
ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' (C:\Users\alaba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py), and this error came from importing pims.api

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing a different version of pims==0.5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).